# Mat Tabs: Is there a way in selectedTabChange to use selected tab component methods?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

When I'm using selectedTabChange you can get selected tab index. Is there a way to get tab component reference to use its methods?

I'm doing a dynamic tabpanel that every tab inside it has enought information to load itself, so when I want to load it I just have to use a single method in there. Now I want to call this method from the tabpanel selectedTabChange listener. When you use this listener you can get the selected tab index but I didn't find out any way of getting its component reference which would allow me to use its methods.

Tabpanel (HTML):

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="onClickPestanya($event)">

    <mat-tab 
        *ngFor="let subfase of subfases;"
        label="{{ subfase.tabTitle }}"> 

        <app-panel-subfase 
            style="display: flex; flex-grow: 1" 
            *ngIf="someId"
            [(someCode)]="subfase.code">
        </app-panel-subfase>

    </mat-tab>

</mat-tab-group>
```

Tabpanel (Typescript):

```
onClickPestanya(event: MatTabChangeEvent): void {
        const me = this;

        me.activeTab = event.index;
        //There I should get tab component reference
}
```

Tab (Typescript):

```
cargarTab(): void {
        //loading tab info
    }
```

I want to load tabs everytime I select it in the tabpanel. I did something similar to this before but with a static tabpanel where I can use child component methods with the @ViewChild directive but this is not an option for a dynamic panel. Another option would be to create and destroy the panel every time that selected panel changes to load it after creating it but I neither have the knowledge to do this.

Comment: I found a solution for this, in the html I modified the if directive like this:
*ngIf="iterId && activeTab === i" 
So if a tab is not selected it won't render until it's selected. In ngOnInit I'm loading the panel so now everytime that I go to another tab it loads.

I don't know if this is the best way to do this, but for now I think is enought.